# How to access Siri Remote play/pause button and override menu button

Tags: swift, tvos, uitapgesturerecognizer, siri-remote

How can I access the play/pause button with the Siri remote and override the menu button? I am currently using this, but it is not working for me. My program crashes when I use this code but only when I call it four example pressing the pause button 
The coders is currently positioned below didMoveToView next to touchesBegan

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Apple TV Siri Remote button presses?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32576834/2108547)

Comment: Apple's Swift example: [Using Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html).

Comment: @DanielStorm  I tried this already but it crashes the application

Comment: What does your `handleTap:` function look like?

Comment: func tapped(){
        print("check")
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving the `tapRecognizer` selector into my previously set up touch handler function so the code looks like this now:

```
private func handleTouches(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
    for touch in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        lastTouch = touchLocation

        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)];
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }
}

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        print("Menu button released")
    }     
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you're calling a function called `handleTap:` that receives a parameter but you don't have a function called `handleTap:`. That's what `action` represents in this line:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
```

Change your `func tapped()` to:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        print("Menu button released")
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried this it still causes a crash. let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)];
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    
    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("button tapped")
    }

Comment: it still seems like the that the selector is not calling the function correctly GameScene handleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x126733890

Comment: It's strangely still not working; I used a different way to do what I wanted, using the touchpad, but I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: @FerdinandLösch not a problem. You should post an answer with your solution for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following for Swift 4 (as per question: [@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift))

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

---

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        print("Menu button released")
    }
}
```