# tvOS: detecting pause button press

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, tvos, siri-remote

I am trying to detect when a user presses the play/pause button on the remote. I have created a tap gesture recognizer and attached it to the view of a AVPlayerViewController subclass.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(togglePlayPause:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypePlayPause)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];


- (void)togglePlayPause:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Toggle play/pause");
    if ([self playing])
    {
        NSLog(@"    Pause");
        [self.player pause];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"    Play");
        [self.player play];
    }
}
```

The gesture fires fine when the "play" button is pressed but does not when the "pause" button is pressed. Any ideas why?

Comment: Here's how you do it: [How to detect Apple TV Siri Remote button presses?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32585251/2108547). Edit your question to include your `togglePlayPause:` function. I'd image that's the issue.

Comment: No. The function isn't even being called when the "pause" button is being pressed.

Comment: Mind the `:` in your `togglePlayPause`. Does your function take an argument?

Comment: Yea it returns the gesture recognizer