# Touch location Siri Remote tvOS Swift

Tags: swift, tvos, siri-remote

Is it possible to detect the coordinates of the tap on the surface of the Siri Remote? I would wish to recognized the left half and right half and assign a function to it when the user is doing a double tap on it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32576834/2108547

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm searching. In that question it's explained how to recognized the touch of the button. I would wish to know if it's possible to grab the coordinates when the finger is touching the Siri Remote

Comment: AFAIK that’s not possible as the initial coordinate of all touches is (0, 0). It’s relative to initial touch, not the touch pad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get location of the tap. The coordinates of any gesture in Siri Remote always start from the center of the touchpad.